# How to connect Domain bought from Godaddy to my host from another vendor?

Tags: dns, gmail, web-hosting

My domain in godaddy.com is configured with google email server, now I want to host my website from another vendor with that domain. How to do that?

Comment: What's the host service? Is it one of the major cloud services? If you elaborate on your hosting provider, we might be able to provide more specific help.

Comment: Host provider is hostingraja.com

Comment: Alright, please see my answer below for the general case (get the IP of your server, and then set the `A` record in your Domain's DNS settings on Godaddy). You might need to contact the hosting provider to ensure that 1. your server has a static IP, and 2. ask what that IP is. They might also have guidance for connecting your domain name to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll get the IP address of your host, and create the appropriate `A Record` in your DNS settings on Godaddy. If you're getting hosting from one of the major cloud providers (Azure, Aws, Google Cloud, etc.) they likely have detailed tutorials or even automated tasks to do this for you.

In Azure Web Apps, for example, your application has a tab for **Custom Domains** where you'll be given instructions on how to connect a domain name to your web app instance. As you can see, you'll get access to the public IP of your server on this page, and you'll be able to set the proper DNS settings in Godaddy using that IP.

[image: Azure Web Apps Custom Domains]

Get that **IP address**, and create the following 2 records in your Godaddy Domain DNS settings:

1. Type: `A`, Name: `@`, Value: `IP of your server`
2. Type: `CNAME`, Name: `www`, Value: `@`

[image]